# How to prevent tiny bars on charts in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://d.pr/i/U5bb/4n26fLZr

Here's an example of a chart of ours. Pretty unreadable, yea? Is there an easy, dynamic way avoid this? I've tried implementing a dynamic height, but the problem is I can never seem to find the sweet spot that accommodates a smaller number of bars, and a larger number of bars. I feel like this has to be a problem that others have encountered before. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a log axis scale?

Comment: @wergeld what's that?

Comment: -http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type. Log axis is different type where the basic explanation is that one unit of increase in a tick mark is equivalent to an order of magnitude change.

Comment: I think that you have too many bars for this height, and one of solutions can be increase height / use stacking. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked / manipulate pointPadding / groupPadding. All parameters are available [here](api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this by doing the following:

1) determine height of non-data elements on the chart (ie, explicitly set the top and bottom margins, and add them together to get a `base_height` for the chart

2) determine how much space I want each bar to take, including bar width, and padding between bars, and set as my `height_multiplier` (I usually end up going for 20-25 pixels, personally)

3) on pulling my data, determine how many bars will be needed, and set as my `bar_count`

4) calculate: `chart_height = base_height + (bar_count * height_multiplier)`

5) Pass that value to the html to set the height of the chart's containing element.

If your data will vary so much that the chart height in your example works some times, but then you have as many data points as you've posted there, there simply will not be a 'sweet spot' that will handle both extremes well.